# Custom Asp.net mvc 5 authentication without using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

How do you create a custom ASP.NET MVC 5 Auth without using the UserStore of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework??

Comment: by using universal providers ? not tested with MVC5, but [with MVC4](https://vspsamples.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Do you want to avoid EF? Shoe given you a stub of how you can implement your own `UserStore` that might not depend on EF. It is a chore to implement though...

Comment: I find that most people who don't want to use Identity either have very specific requirements, or they don't understand it and think it's too much work (it's absolutely not, it's bone dead simple, it's much more work to implement it yourself)

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is implement the same interfaces that the Userstore for `Identity.Entityframework` uses.

`User` will be your user class

```
public class MyUserStore<TUser> : 
    IUserLoginStore<TUser, int>, 
    IUserClaimStore<TUser, int>, 
    IUserRoleStore<TUser, int>, 
    IUserPasswordStore<TUser, int>, 
    IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser, int>, 
    IUserStore<TUser, int>, 
    IDisposable where TUser : User
{
   //Implement the interfaces you need
}
```

Then pass your `MyUserStore` into the `UserManager` each request

```
new UserManager<User, int>(new MyUserStore<User>(new MyContext()))
```

Comment: Thats a bit of work.. but thanks.. Is there any other way to make the login/logout simple? Asp.NET MVC 5 Default AccountController seems complex.. I just have a simple user class with username and password stored in the DB..

Comment: Are you looking to make it simple or not use `Identity.Entityframework`? Because that namespace is really meant to do a bunch of the grunt work for you.

Comment: Is there any guide out there to customizing these things?

Comment: Simple and Dont wanna use the Identity.EntityFramework.. I want to adapt it to my application I already have my DbContexts.. and a DbSet<User> the User class is what I wrote..

Comment: There isn't really a way. Either you use the hookups to identity from identity.entityframework or you implement your own hookups. The other option is ditching the usermanager entirely and creating identities manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab UserStore.cs template from the following project on GitHub and tweak it as you like, it will allow you to get rid of the dependency on Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.

https://github.com/kriasoft/AspNet-Server-Template -> ./src/App.Server/Data/UserStore.cs

(disclaimer: I'm the author of this project template)