# MVC5 authentication individual user accounts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

We want to setup a new MVC5 project that uses the individual user accounts authentication functions.

The users are stored in an existing sql server database. I've seen solutions on how to generate the auto generated tables from the mdf file to sql server, but that's not the solutions.

What we would like to accomplish is that the user validation, registration, password reset, etc is using our existing rest client to do that by posting the data. Can this be done using the build in accountController, or do we select 'none' on authentication when setting up the project, and do all by custom code?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article: [Overview of Custom Storage Providers for ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity#userstore) Note that storage in your case means a REST service.

Edit: Perhaps this is the better article for your scenario:
[Implementing a Custom MySQL ASP.NET Identity Storage Provider](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider)

Comment: Did find some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488716/custom-asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-without-using-microsoft-aspnet-identity-enti http://aspnetguru.com/customize-authentication-to-your-own-set-of-tables-in-asp-net-mvc-5/ but its unclear to me because i'm using VB